# Override New for a single record type with lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

What I would like to do is override the New button but only for a specific Record Type.

The normal functionality is that if you have more than one record type, clicking new will take you to a first step where you select the record type and then clicking next takes you to the layout for the record type selected.

I want to keep the first step, and for all but one record type keep the standard creation pages. For the one recordtype I want to display a lightning component when it's selected in the first step. I'm hoping I don't have to rewrite the first wizard step, any ideas?

Here is my component and controller:

COMPONENT

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="GoogleAddressSearchController">
    <aura:attribute name="propertyRecord" type="Community_Lead__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="showModalBox" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="placeholder" type="string" default="Search address" />
    <aura:attribute name="AddressList" type="String[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                targetFields="{!v.propertyRecord}"
                fields="Id,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Email__c, Phone__c, Referral_Source__c,
                        Address__c, City__c, State__c,  Zip__c, Country__c"
                mode="EDIT" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
   
    <!-- Initial Fields -->
<lightning:input  aura:id="propName" name="propName" label="First Name" required="true" />
<lightning:input aura:id="propBeds" name="propBeds" label="Last Name" required="true"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="propBaths" name="propBaths" label="Email" />
<lightning:input aura:id="propPrice" name="propPrice" label="Phone" />
<lightning:select aura:id="propStatus" name="propStatus" label="Referral Source" value="" required="true" >
        <option value="--None--">--None--</option>
        <option value="Community Resource">Community Resource</option>
        <option value="Event">Event</option>
        <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
         <option value="Physician Office">Physician Office</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
</lightning:select>  
    
    <!-- Address fields -->
 <lightning:input label="Address" onclick="{!c.OpenModal}" type="search" class="slds-lookup__search-input" placeholder="Search Address"  />     
       <lightning:input name="Street" label="Street" class="StreetCs" aura:id="Street" value="{!v.propertyRecord.Address__c}"/>  
       <lightning:input name="City" label="City" aura:id="City" value="{!v.propertyRecord.City__c}"/>
       <lightning:input name="State" label="State/Province" aura:id="State" value="{!v.propertyRecord.State__c}"/>  
       <lightning:input name="Zip/Postal Code" label="Zip/Postal Code" aura:id="Zip" value="{!v.propertyRecord.Zip__c}"/>
       <lightning:input name="Country" label="Country" aura:id="Country" value="{!v.propertyRecord.Country__c}"/>
    
<!-- Modal box starts -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showModalBox}">
        <div class="" style="">
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate"><b>Address Search</b></h2>
                    </header>
                    
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="slds-size_12-of-12 slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right slds-input-has-icon_group-right">
                            <lightning:ButtonIcon size="medium" iconName="utility:close"  onclick="{!c.clear}" class="slds-m-right_xx-large slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" variant="bare"/>
                            <lightning:input name="searchKey"
                                             class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-input slds-combobox__input"
                                             value="{!v.searchKey}"
                                             onkeyup ="{!c.keyPressController}"
                                             placeholder="Enter address.."/> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- list of address display -->
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.AddressList))}">
                            <div class="Address-listbox" role="listbox">
                                <ul aura:id="Address-listbox" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="presentation">
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.AddressList}" var="addList">
                                        <li role="presentation"
                                            onclick="{!c.selectOption}"
                                            data-value="{!addList.place_id}"
                                            class="slds-listbox__item">
                                            <span id="listbox-option-unique-id-01"
                                                  class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta"
                                                  role="option">
                                                <span class="slds-media__body slds-m-left_xx-small slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                                                    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-bottom_small">
                                                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-10">  
                                                            <lightning:ButtonIcon size="medium" iconName="utility:checkin" class="slds-input__icon" variant="bare"/></div>
                                                        <div class="slds-m-left_medium slds-col slds-size_8-of-10"> 
                                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity"><b>{!addList.main_text}</b></span>
                                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity slds-m-top_xxx-small">{!addList.secondary_text}</span></div>
                                                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-10"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeModal}" />
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
        </aura:if>
<!-- Modal box ends here -->
        
    
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelDialog}" />
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRecord}"/>

</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER

```
({
    
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
component.find("forceRecord").getNewRecord(
        "Community_Lead__c",
        null,
        false,
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.propertyRecord");
            var error = component.get("v.recordError");
            if (error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    );

},
        OpenModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.AddressList', null);
        component.set("v.showModalBox", true);
    },
        //On search of address get address list from the API
    keyPressController: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAddressRecommendations(component,event);
    }, 
        //Get city, state, country and other details from selected address
    selectOption:function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAddressDetailsByPlaceId(component, event);
    }, 
    //close the modal window on click of cancel button
    closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.showModalBox", false);
    }, 
    //Clear the address list on the user interface
    clear: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.clearAddressList(component, event);
    },
    
  saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
component.set("v.propertyRecord.First_Name__c", component.find('propName').get("v.value"));    
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Last_Name__c", component.find('propBeds').get("v.value") );
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Email__c",component.find('propBaths').get("v.value")  );
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Phone__c", component.find('propPrice').get("v.value") );
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Referral_Source__c", component.find("propStatus").get("v.value"));
   component.set("v.propertyRecord.Address__c", component.find('Street').get("v.value") );
   component.set("v.propertyRecord.City__c", component.find('City').get("v.value") );
   component.set("v.propertyRecord.State__c", component.find('State').get("v.value") );
   component.set("v.propertyRecord.Zip__c", component.find('Zip').get("v.value") );
   component.set("v.propertyRecord.Country__c", component.find('Country').get("v.value") );
var tempRec = component.find("forceRecord");
tempRec.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
    console.log(result.state);
    var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if (result.state === "SUCCESS") {
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Saved",
            "message": "The record was saved."
        });
        resultsToast.fire(); 
        var recId = result.recordId;
helper.navigateTo(component, recId);

    } else if (result.state === "ERROR") {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Error",
            "message": "There was an error saving the record: " + JSON.stringify(result.error)
        });
        resultsToast.fire();
    } else {
        console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + result.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
    }
}));

},
    
    
    
    cancelDialog : function(component, helper) {
        var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
homeEvt.setParams({
    "scope": "Community_Lead__c"
});
homeEvt.fire();

}

  
})
```

Comment: You can't explicitly override for just one record type. You need to first get the record type Id provided by lightning:hasPageReference (Aura) or Lightning Navigation Service (LWC), then retrieve the name for the record type (optional, but recommended), and if necessary, use the navigation services above to redirect to the standard new page if its not the correct record type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I am brand new to lightning components, is there any way you could sample the code or point me to a sample of the ideas you mentioned?